# What type of NSButton is it? In "About This Mac" window

Tags: xcode, macos, styles, appkit, nsbutton

What type of NSButton are those 6 buttons on right side of the screenshot? 
Is it standard control? How can I implement such buttons?

They look like inline buttons but they are not.

[image: About This Mac]

Answer (score 2):

That's an inline with image "NSFollowLinkFreeStandingTemplate", position "leading" and alignment "left", made in interface editor of xcode:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But when highlight and click your solution looks different. There's no background appear.

Comment: Just play with parameters.